# What is the correct way to configure DEQWAIT to work with multiple threads?

Tags: ibm-midrange

Has anyone here worked with *USRQ? There is a problem when exchanging between threads via usrq
There are two threads that are quite intensively exchanging messages via KEYED USRQ (one sends messages with the key KEY1 and reads with the key KEY2, the second vice versa).
The problem is that if all this works in two different jobs, then everything is fine. But when in two different threads of the same task, problems with "sticking" begin - a message that is definitely sent from one thread becomes available for reading from another after a long time (maximum was fixed up to 120 seconds).
Judging by the stack, both threads are currently in the message waiting state (DEQWAIT) - one thread has sent a message and is waiting for a response message from the second, but the second cannot receive the sent message for a long time.
I repeat - the problem is only when exchanging messages between two threads within the same job. If the exchange is between two different jobs, everything works very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used *USRQ, but when I use *DTAQ, I always make the queues one way. It makes managing them easier. You can still use a keyed queue to retrieve a specific message, but in general the reader doesn't have to worry about whether a specific message is for them or not. if the queue is two way, then there will be readers on both sides of the queue and there must be measures taken to ensure the messages written on one side of the queue only get read by the other side of the queue. It could be that issue that causes locks.

Comment: The problem is that when the client and server work in different jobs, the difference between sending and receiving a message does not exceed 1.5 milliseconds (average over 500,000 packets is about 10-15 microseconds). Problems begin when the client and the server work in different flows of one job.

Comment: There is a good chance that because there is only one object, the multiple threads could be locking each other out. I'm not sure what all the locking looks like, but you have multiple threads in a single job (which share an address space) all trying to write and read the same queue at the same time. There is a lot of opportunity for contention. I would start by making one queue for requests, and another queue for replies. That should be a simple change. Then see if you have similar contention.

Comment: Yes thank you. This option cannot be ruled out either.